# Посоветуйте, где можно научиться программированию на Питоне, сайт, книга, по вашему опыту

Tags: python

уважаемые пользователи stack overflow. Посоветуйте пожалуйста начинающему программисту на Python найти нормальную, хорошую книгу, либо сайт, где можно начать изучать Python.
Всем большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую этот roadmap для изучения https://github.com/GnuriaN/Python-Roadmap

Comment: Большое вам спасибо!